# Form select method in Kohana includes "multiple" attribute in HTML if not NULL

Tags: forms, select, kohana

I'm using the form::select helper in Kohana 3.2 to generate a select input with the following code (formatted for display here):

```
form::select('id_plyta', $plyta, $plyta_selected, 
    array('style' => 'width:300px', 'class' => 'sock_depend'));
```

This code generates the following HTML (formatted for display here):

```
<select name="id_plyta" class="sock_depend" style="width:300px" 
    multiple="multiple">
    ...
</select>
```

The problem is that it is outputting with an extra `multiple="multiple"` attribute in the HTML. I don't want that to be a part of it.

If I put a NULL instead of `$plyta_selected` then it works fine.

How do I get rid of `multiple="multiple"` and why is it even there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you check out the list of parameters it accepts, pay attention to the third:

```
 * @param   string   input name
 * @param   array    available options
 * @param   mixed    selected option string, or an array of selected options
 * @param   array    html attributes
```

When sending the paramters to the `select` method of the `Form` class, if the third parameter is an array, the helper will automatically include the `multiple="multiple"` to allow it to pre-select more than one option in the drop down select.

If you only send a string value, then it will not create a multibox, will not include the `multiple` HTML input attribute and it will only pre-select the single value.

Comment: My bad, I was passing array Thanks !